# A curious series for $L(2,(\frac{-3}{\cdot}))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, l-functions, combinatorial-identities

Let
$$K:=L\left(2,\left(\frac{-3}{\cdot}\right)\right)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(\frac k3)}{k^2}=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(3j+1)^2}-\frac1{(3j+2)^2}\right),$$ where $(\frac k3)$ is the Legendre symbol.
Recently, I found the following (conjectural) curious identity for the constant $K$:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(42k^2-27k+4)(-9)^k}{k^3(2k-1)\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\binom{4k}{2k}}=-6K.\label{1}\tag{1}$$
The series has converging rate $-1/48$, and so \eqref{1} can be easily checked numerically.

Motivated by \eqref{1}, I also conjecture that
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-9)^k\left((42k^2-27k+4)(H_{3k-1}-H_{k-1})-10k+3\right)}{k^3(2k-1)\binom{2k}k\binom{3k}k\binom{4k}{2k}}=-\frac{8\pi^3}{27\sqrt3}.\label{2}\tag{2}$$

**QUESTION.** How to deduce the identities \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}?

Your comments are welcome!